How to do redirect to another page in inside the function by "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1"?
I have an issue with redirect to another page. I can't use useNavigate() inside the function. Because it's not an component. redirect also not working. How can i redirect?
import { redirect, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { ILogin } from "../Pages/Login/ILogin";
import { decode } from "./encodeDecode";

export const parseToken = () => {
  const nav = useNavigate();
  try {
    const token: ILogin = decode(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    return token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert("Invalid Credentials");
    localStorage.clear();
    redirect("/login");
    nav("/login");
  }
};


when call redirect it's not working
when call nav it's throw an error as
  Line 6:15:  React Hook "useNavigate" is called in function "parseToken" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

webpack compiled with 1 error and 1 warning

I need a solution for redirecting in function.

How do you call parseToken?

Sorry, it's a sensitive part. I need to know if it's failed, then redirect to the login page.

Where and how is parseToken being called and used? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] and more complete details.

You are mixing a bunch of concepts. The first is that redirect() and useNavigate() are two different things: redirect() is just an utility that returns a Response to be used to redirect inside loaders and actions. useNavigate() is an hook that allows you to programmatically navigate from a component.
Since useNavigate() is an hook, it follows the hooks rules, meaning that it cannot be called inside a function, but nothing stops you to pass the nav function as a parameter of parseToken():

const parseToken = (navigate: NavigateFunction) => {
  try {
    const token: ILogin = decode(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    return token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert("Invalid Credentials");
    localStorage.clear();
    navigate("/login");
  }
};

export function MyComponent() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ...
    parseToken(navigate);
    ...
  }, [...])

  return <div>{...}</div>
}


Okay. I got it. And one more thing, I am not mixing the concepts. I am just showing to all, that I have already tried this... I know this method too, to pass as a parameter.
Anyway, thanks for your suggestions.

change component name from parseToken to ParseToken
and use like <ParseToken/>

The redirect function is not part of the standard React Router API and seems to be a misunderstanding or a mix-up with the useNavigate hook or the Navigate component.

Your code should look like -
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { ILogin } from "../Pages/Login/ILogin";
import { decode } from "./encodeDecode";
const MyComp = () => {
const nav = useNavigate();
const parseToken = () => {
try {
const token: ILogin = decode(localStorage.getItem("token"));
return token;
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
alert("Invalid Credentials");
localStorage.clear();
nav("/login");

}
};
export default MyComp;

I need to get userName from it.
const userName = MyComp()?.userName;
userChangePasswordForm.setFieldValue("username", userName);
if I do like this, it's throw error as
const userName = MyComp()?.userName;
userChangePasswordForm.setFieldValue("username", userName);

@HarshitSingh Please edit the answer to add additional information instead of posting it in comments.

@DalijaPrasnikar I'm new here,when i was posting the code,it is giving some error,this is why I posted this in comments

@HarshitSingh Which error? It is possible that you haven't properly formatted the code.  Please see How do I format my code blocks?

The error you're seeing regarding useNavigate is pretty self explanatory - you cannot call a hook in a function that's neither a React function (starts with a capital latter) or a custom hook (starts with use). Check out Rules of Hooks page in the React docs.
As for the redirect function, it should be used in a loader. Make sure you've set up your router as a with createBrowserRouter to be able to use data API's.

then what I do in this situation?

try to return redirect("/login"); like THIS
or return <Navigate to="/login"/>
